# ORM Django, Relacion Muchos Muchos

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

En este momento estoy desarrollando un proyecto, en el que una de las secciones permite hacer una serie de anuncios, la idea es que tengan varias imágenes relacionadas, de la forma en que desarrollé esa sección, solo me permite para almacenar una imagen por anuncio, y me gustaría saber cómo puedo agregar varias al mismo tiempo, luego presento el modelo, los formularios y la vista para crearlo.

> > Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete= models.CASCADE,default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    id_location= models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    id_ad_kind= models.ForeignKey(AdKind, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    id_category= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    id_unit= models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default = None, blank=True, null=True)
    ad_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ad_description= models.TextField()
    price= models.FloatField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ad_images= models.ManyToManyField(Image, related_name="get_images_ad")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ad_name

    class Meta():
        verbose_name= "Anuncio"
        verbose_name_plural= "Anuncios"

class Image(models.Model):
    img_route= models.ImageField(upload_to="Images", verbose_name="Ruta de la Imagen")

    class Meta():
        verbose_name= "Imagen"
        verbose_name_plural= "Imagenes"
```

> > Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class AdCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model= Ad
        fields=('ad_name', 'ad_description','price','id_location',
                'id_ad_kind','id_category','id_unit',)


class AdImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model= Image
        fields=('img_route',)
```

> > Archivo `views.py`:

```
def AdCreate(request):
    model = Ad
    if  request.method == "POST" :
        ad_form= AdCreateForm(request.POST)
        img_form= AdImageForm(request.POST,request.FILES )
        print("img es "+ str(img_form.is_valid()))
        print(img_form)
        if ad_form.is_valid() and img_form.is_valid():
            img= img_form.save()        
            ad= ad_form.save(False)
            ad.id_user = request.user
            ad= ad_form.save()
            ad.ad_images.add(img)
            ad.save()
            print("Almacenado")
            return render(request,'ad/ad_list.html')
    else:
        ad_form=AdCreateForm()
        img_form=AdImageForm()

    return render(request,'ad/ad_create.html',{'Ad_form': ad_form,'img_form':img_form})
```

Comment: Quieres que subir varias imágenes atraves del modelo Ad? por así decirlo.

Comment: Si en efecto, la realidad es que no se muy bien como hacerlo, la idea es que al modelo ad , puedan corresponderle varias imagenes, pero no se como hacer el formulario y la vista para reflejar ese resultado, por los momentos asi como esta puedo amacenar ad pero con una sola imagen

Comment: Ok ya publique mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 0):

Para subir varias imágenes a atraves del modelo `Ad`, por así decirlo es crear un modelo aparte que se relacione con el modelo `Ad`, pues no existe un campo que permita subir varias imágenes tipo "MultiImageField".

El modelo sera de la siguiente manera:

```
class AdImage(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'ad_images')
```

Cada instancia sera una imagen del modelo guardada.

Para que atraves de tu formulario puedas subir varias imágenes seria de la siguiente manera (recuerda mostrar el campo en el HTML xd):

```
class AdCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    images_field = forms.ImageField(widget = forms.FileInput(attrs = {'multiple': True}))

    class Meta():
        model= Ad
        fields=('ad_name', 'ad_description','price','id_location',
                'id_ad_kind','id_category','id_unit',)
```

Por ultimo seria hacerle una pequeña modificasion a tu vista, de la siguiente manera. (Por cierto no te recomiendo que tu vista maneje 2 o mas formularios a la ves).

```
def AdCreate(request):
    model = Ad
    if request.method == "POST" :
        ad_form= AdCreateForm(request.POST)
        if ad_form.is_valid():
            instance = ad_form.save()

            # Guardamos las varias imagenes subidas
            for image in request.FILES.getlist('images_field'):
                AdImage.objects.create(ad = instance, image = image)            

            return render(request,'ad/ad_list.html')
    else:
        ad_form=AdCreateForm()

    return render(request,'ad/ad_create.html',{'Ad_form': ad_form})
```

Y listo eso seria todo, es la única manera de hacerlo, pues no existe un campo que permita varias imágenes a menos que utilices una app de terceros que lo implemente.

Por cierto para acceder a las imágenes de una instancia del modelo `Ad` seria de la siguiente manera:

```
ad_instance.adimage_set.all()
```

Que te retornara un QuerySet con las imágenes. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias intentare realizar esos cambios.